# Non superscript citations for figures

Tags: floats, formatting, citing, natbib

Is it possible to reference figures like so

```
taken from \emph{ref. \cite{reference}}
```

with non superscript numbers, while leaving the rest of the references in the bulk of the document untouched? This is using BibTeX and the [RSC (Royal Society of
Chemistry) style](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/rsc).

Comment: `\cite` references entries in a bibliography, while you mention referencing figures. Are you referencing a figure in a some bib entry? Also, the default reference style for `\cite` (and `\ref`) is not superscripted. What `\documentclass` are you using? Even better, please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that clearly illustrates your problem.

Comment: It's the srcbook document class. I'm trying to reference a figure in a bib entry. Instead of putting "Taken from ref. 3" I would like to cite it instead incase the ordering of my bibliography changes at some point.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something here, but I still don't understand, since using `\cite` would modify the output when the ordering of the bibliography changes - this is a default feature (for `\ref` as well). Please include a small minimal example of a document that includes your current setup. Also include a screen shot of the output so members can clearly distinguish between the current and desired output.

Comment: Using \cite does exactly that, however the RSC bibliography style uses superscripted references. When explicitly referencing a figure , instead of having "Taken from ref.^2", as I would get using \cite{reference}. I would like the reference number to be in normal case. If this still isn't clear, I can add an example.

Comment: @Leda: Please add a minimal example otherwise your question will be closed as too localized.

Comment: Why not just use `\citenum`?

Comment: @JosephWright Dang. Indeed. Answer updated. Consider a random answer of yours upvoted.

Comment: @JosephWright As you probably can imagine, the first six random answers of yours had already been upvoted by me. Not number seven, though. ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you load `natbib` with its `super` option, you could take the code `natbib` is executing in case `super` *isn't* used and add it to the code executed at the start of floats.

EDIT: Or, as Joseph Wright has commented, *"Why not just use `\citenum`?"*

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[super]{natbib}

% \makeatletter
% \g@addto@macro\@floatboxreset{%
%   \let\NAT@mbox=\mbox
%   \let\@cite\NAT@citenum
%   \let\NAT@space\NAT@spacechar
%   \let\NAT@super@kern\relax
% }
% \makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption{A figure (taken from \emph{ref. \citenum{A01}})}
\end{figure}

Some text.\citep{A01}

\bibliographystyle{rsc}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]