# Temporarily disable superscript in citation

Tags: citing, superscripts

I use superscripted citation style by using `\setcitestyle{super}` in LaTeX preamble, which done the job as I wanted. However, there are several region, in which I need to temporarily disable the superscript. For example the sentence

> This figure is reproduced from reference [1]

doesn't look right with [1] being superscripted.

How to achieve that? Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: I've just realized that my question is basically the same as this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50476/non-superscript-citations-for-figures, as well as http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36235/bibtex-natbib-with-super-does-not-allow-using-occasional-citet. Sorry for not doing proper search before.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The following example changes `\setcitestyle` locally and puts it in macro `\citen`.
`\setcitestyle` of package `natbib` (2010/09/13 8.31b) contains a space right at the beginning of the macro definition by an uncommented end of line, the trick with `\romannumeral` removes this space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[square]{natbib}
\setcitestyle{super}

\newcommand*{\citen}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \romannumeral-`\x % remove space at the beginning of \setcitestyle
    \setcitestyle{numbers}%
    \cite{#1}%
  \endgroup   
}

\begin{document}
Package \textsf{accsupp}\cite{oberdiek:accsupp}.
This figure is reproduce from reference~\citen{oberdiek:zref}.
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\raggedright
\bibliography{oberdiek-bundle}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Inside moving arguments (e.g., `\caption`) macro `\citen` can be protected using `\protect` or by using `\DeclareRobustCommand` for the definition:

```
\newcommand*{\citen}{}% generate error, if `\citen` is already in use
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\citen}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \romannumeral-`\x % remove space at the beginning of \setcitestyle
    \setcitestyle{numbers}%
    \cite{#1}%
  \endgroup
}
```

Comment: Cool! Thanks very much. If I got enough reputation, I'll definitely vote up this answer.

Comment: Ah, I just realized that there are errors if I try to put that inside a figure caption. The LaTEX error are "Argument of \@iforloop has an extra}.", "Paragraph ended before \@iforloop was complete." and "Extra \else.". Do you have any idea? Thanks.

Comment: @Indra Add `\protect`. Macro `\citen` is fragile because of fragile `\setcitestyle`. Or use `\DeclareRobustCommand` instead of `\newcommand`.